# duplicate rows and swap clumns based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following table:

```
    name    a0  a1  type    val
0   name1   1   0   AB     100
1   name1   2   0   AB     105
2   name2   1   2   BB     110
3   name3   1   0   AN     120
```

and I want to do this.

For every type I see where the type name does not contain the same 2 letters, I want to duplicate the row and swap the a0 and a1 columns and the letters of the type column. So, my result will be:

```
     name   a0  a1  type    val
0   name1   1   0   AB     100
1   name1   0   1   BA     100
2   name1   2   0   AB     105
3   name1   0   2   BA     105
4   name2   1   2   BB     110
5   name3   1   0   AN     120
6   name3   0   1   NA     120
```

Note that for example for the same name we can have the same type but different a0 and a1 (and hence val).

So, we can have name1 and type AB as in the first two lines of the original table.

I tried:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 'a0':[1, 2, 1, 1], 'a1':[0, 0, 2, 0], 'type':['AB', 'AB', 'BB', 'AN'], 'val':[100,105, 110, 120]})


for idx in df1.index:

    a1 = df1.loc[idx, 'a0']
    a0 = df1.loc[idx, 'a1']
    val = df1.loc[idx, 'val']
    name = df1.loc[idx, 'name']

    if df1.loc[idx, 'type'] == 'AB':
        new_type = 'BA'

    elif df1.loc[idx, 'type'] == 'AN':
        new_type = 'NA'

    row = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'a0':a0 , 'a1':a1 , 'type':new_type, 'val':val}, index=np.arange(idx))
    df1 = df1.append(row, ignore_index=False)
    df1 = df1.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

but it gives me:

```
    name    a0  a1  type    val
0   name1   1   0   AB     100
1   name1   2   0   BA     105
2   name1   0   2   BA     105
3   name1   2   0   BA     105
4   name1   0   2   BA     105
5   name1   2   0   BA     105
6   name1   0   2   BA     105
7   name1   2   0   AB     105
8   name2   1   2   BB     110
9   name3   1   0   AN     120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create mask for identify values with 2 different letters, create new DataFrame by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), swap values in columns, join together and sorting by index, last create default index values:

```
mask = df['type'].apply(set).str.len() == 2

df1 = df[mask].assign(type=lambda x: df['type'].str[1] + df['type'].str[0])
df1[['a0','a1']] = df1[['a1','a0']].to_numpy()
#pandas below
#df1[['a0','a1']] = df1[['a1','a0']].values

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    name  a0  a1 type  val
0  name1   1   0   AB  100
1  name1   0   1   BA  100
2  name1   2   0   AB  105
3  name1   0   2   BA  105
4  name2   1   2   BB  110
5  name3   1   0   AN  120
6  name3   0   1   NA  120
```

Comment: OP wants to swap `a0`& `a1` as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
def myfunc(x):
    x['type']=x['type'][::-1]
    x[['a0','a1']]=x[['a1','a0']].values
    return x
```

---

```
m=df.type.apply(set).str.len().gt(1)
pd.concat([df,df.loc[m].apply(myfunc,axis=1)],ignore_index=True).sort_values(['name','val'])
```

---

```
    name  a0  a1 type  val
0  name1   1   0   AB  100
4  name1   0   1   BA  100
1  name1   2   0   AB  105
5  name1   0   2   BA  105
2  name2   1   2   BB  110
3  name3   1   0   AN  120
6  name3   0   1   NA  120
```